# typescript class constructor inferring types based on args of its function as argument

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Sorry if the title is not very clear, but I don't know how to phrase my problem better.

I have a `Process` class:

```
class Process {
  readonly fn: Function;
  readonly parameters: any | any[]; // doing sth here to have the types inferred based on `fn` args
  nextMessage: Message | null;

  constructor(fn:Function, parameters: any|any[]){
    this.fn = fn;
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }
}
```

when instantiating a new Process Object:

```
function doTask(task: string){
  console.log(`doing ${task}`);
}
const message = new Process(doTask, "Something");
```

I want to have type check on the `parameter` that i pass to Message constructor to match the type on the function argument.
like, in the code above, if I pass a number instead of string, I want to get an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way is to have a type parameters that represents the parameter types of the function as a tuple:

```
class Process<T extends any[]> {
  readonly fn: (...args: T) => any;
  readonly parameters: T; // doing sth here to have the types inferred based on `fn` args
  
  constructor(fn: (...args: T) => any, parameters: T){
    this.fn = fn;
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }
}

function doTask(task: string){
  console.log(`doing ${task}`);
}
const message = new Process(doTask, ["Something"]);
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKBOB7YBTKAeAKtFAPALigHYAmMYRAngNoC6AfNAN4BQ008KYJiRIl0AGZEAXNAAUAOmlh4AcwhjMASmgBeRhUoBuNhy48+AgA6ywAWxSF4i6Jm3QA9I+g8AlkTnQI+ABbRfFE5ofEQAsAA3FBDAkMpjNGgPQSDOEmgAI0gUdN5oAANhfOhZBT09YF4feABXYFD4cWExKRl5WxV1TSoAGmhTeAsrII7lVnZ2PzcISWF1ISJdCZjpyQGh6xg1frNLTaXoAF8WY5ZBGqJ6tzyeTEgAa3F8B7FqjzkxiqrEEBRJEEQcnE+XcnmgABImM8IPdDvllLpjpUiD5oJYoGA5NFtkQUAB3OBIVBQcS3B59agAIgAyog9r53pTaAigA)

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you have the type Parameters:

```
class Process<F extends Function> {
  readonly fn: F;
  readonly parameters: any | any[]; // doing sth here to have the types inferred based on `fn` args
  nextMessage: Message | null;

  constructor(fn: F, parameters: Parameters<F["apply"]>) {
    this.fn = fn;
    this.parameters = parameters;
  }
}
```

It does exactly what you would expect, extracting the parameter types.

It's implemented like this:

```
/**
 * Obtain the parameters of a function type in a tuple
 */
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any) => any> = T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```